# How do I paste string columns in data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

suppose we have:

```
mydf <- data.frame(a= LETTERS, b = LETTERS, c =LETTERS)
```

Now we want to add a new column, containing a concatenation of all columns. 
So that rows in the new column read "AAA", "BBB", ...

In my mind the following should work?

```
mydf[,"Concat"] <- apply(mydf, 1, paste0)
```

Comment: With the `apply` logic. `mydf["concat"] <- apply(mydf, 1, paste0, collapse = "")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to @akrun's answer, here is a short explanation on why your code didn't work.
What you are passing to `paste0` in your code are vectors and here is the behavior of `paste` and `paste0` with vectors:

```
> paste0(c("A","A","A"))
[1] "A" "A" "A"
```

Indeed, to concatenate a vector, you need to use argument `collapse`:

```
> paste0(c("A","A","A"), collapse="")
[1] "AAA"
```

Consequently, your code should have been:

```
> apply(mydf, 1, paste0, collapse="")
 [1] "AAA" "BBB" "CCC" "DDD" "EEE" "FFF" "GGG" "HHH" "III" "JJJ" "KKK" "LLL" "MMM" "NNN" "OOO" "PPP" "QQQ" "RRR" "SSS" "TTT" "UUU" "VVV"
[23] "WWW" "XXX" "YYY" "ZZZ"
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `do.call` with `paste0` for faster execution

```
mydf[, "Concat"] <- do.call(paste0, mydf)
```